# How to add current month as class for DIV using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add class with the current month, something like `<div class="month march"></div>` using jQuery. That month name will get from system date by default.

Here is an example where the month is printing. But instead how to add as class name.

HTML:

```
<div id="date" class="month"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var months = ['january', 'February', 'march', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];;
var date = new Date();

document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = months[date.getMonth()];
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vet80fk7/)

Comment: Please add your code to your question. Don't expect us to go looking for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery, it would be like that:

```
$('#date').addClass(months[date.getMonth()]);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/610uohbv/)

[`.addClass()` reference](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var months = ['january', 'February', 'march', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];;
var date = new Date();

$('#date').addClass(months[date.getMonth()]);
```